# Does Serilog console write to the IIS log file if stdoutLogEnabled is true?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

I am using Core 2.2 with Serilog via a Console sink. Locally, this works great via Kestrel. My console opens and I get tons of logs. This changes when I go to IIS. If I flip `stdoutLogEnabled` to true, and I create a logs directory and give it "Everyone - modify" ACL I do actually get a file, and I get output:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysites\myapp-api
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

**But then that is it.** My app is throwing 500 errors but nothing gets logged. Locally, in my console window I can see all of those logs. If Serilog logs to console via Stdout then what is the issue?

Also, I tried to add the file sink and configure it, but I could not get Serilog to produce a file. I think maybe I got the path wrong? I assume if I get the above log, ACLs aren't the issue and Serilog should be able to write. But that is another issue.

If it matters I HAVE enabled `<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>` on my web project.

### Serilog Config:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Information"
      }
    },
    // Console logger. Use Web.Config to see this.
    "WriteTo:ConsoleSublogger": {
      "Name": "Logger",
      "Args": {
        "configureLogger": {
          "WriteTo": [
            {
              "Name": "LiterateConsole",
              "Args": {
                "outputTemplate": "DevConf [{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level}] {SourceContext}{NewLine}{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}",
                "theme": "Code"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      // Add full exception details using Serilog.Exceptions https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Serilog.Exceptions.
      "WithExceptionDetails",
      // Add the username and machine name to the logs using Serilog.Enrichers.Environment https://github.com/serilog/serilog-enrichers-environment.
      "WithEnvironmentUserName",
      "WithMachineName",
      // Add the process ID and name to the logs using Serilog.Enrichers.Process https://github.com/serilog/serilog-enrichers-process.
      "WithProcessId",
      "WithProcessName",
      // Add the current thread ID to the logs using Serilog.Enrichers.Thread https://github.com/serilog/serilog-enrichers-thread.
      "WithThreadId"
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "myapp-api"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Are you sure that the console logger is enabled in production? Perhaps it's disabled via configuration.

Comment: It should be. I utilize the Serilog.AspNetCore package combined with the Serilog.Settings.Configuration. My Program.cs reads it right in without any conditions on environment. Pretty much this https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#inline-initialization

Comment: @VictorioBerra Can you share the `Serilog` section from `appSettings.json` file?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Edited the post and added the requested Serilog configuration.

Comment: For `Serilog logs`, you did not configure serilog file log, it should not affect `stdoutLogEnabled`. How did you produce `500 errors`? After it created file, I think it should be ok to log other internal server errors.

Comment: @TaoZhou So i am wrong to assume stdout generated from the Serilog Console sink will NOT be redirected to the stdoutLogFile? That is what is confusing me. The 500 errors are legitimate. The database was down.